# Scoring systems aside from expected value for ad conversions?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am trying to develop a scoring system for ad conversions. I have the type of data you would expect such as click-through rate (proportion) and the dollar amount of the sale. So I know I can develop an expected value scoring system from this type of data. But I want to find is there are other scoring system alternatives.

So, given probability and value data, are there other scoring systems besides expected value?

Comment: Another class of functions you can use are risk measures (e.g. CVaR), where you quantify the `worst-case' events. There's a patent application describing more [here](http://patents.justia.com/patent/20160283970)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from comments:
Another class of functions you can use are risk measures (e.g. CVaR), where you quantify the `worst-case' events. There's a patent application describing more https://patents.justia.com/patent/20160283970 – combo